# Switching Views with no animation - Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to switch views but with no animation such as a cross dissolve, so it goes to a different view with no transition. Just switch straight to the view.

This is the current code:

```
-(IBAction)goNext:(id)sender; {
    NwxtiewController *second = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, try using `animated:NO`...

Comment: Oops lol it works. swear last time I did it, it didnt work. But yay worked this time. thanks

Comment: :D Good one. :D